# Why is my message divided into multiple frames?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, serialization, zeromq

When i send a request to my server or a reply to my client, the message i send is always divided into multiple parts.

So i need to call Receive multiple times to get to the last part/frame.

Why does this happen.. is there a better way of sending and receiving an xml encoded string?

This is the code of my client:

```
  private void SendRequestAsyncTaskStart<T>(object contextObj, T request)
  {
     ZmqContext context = (ZmqContext)contextObj;
     ZmqSocket requestSocket = CreateServerSocket(context);

     SerializeAndSendRequest(request, requestSocket);
  }

  private ZmqSocket CreateServerSocket(ZmqContext context)
  {
     var client = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REQ);
     client.Connect(_requestReplyEndpoint);
     client.Linger = TimeSpan.Zero;
     client.ReceiveReady += PollInReplyHandler;

     return client;
 }

 public static string Serialize(this object obj)
  {
     string result;

     using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
        {
           var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
           serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
           memoryStream.Position = 0;
           result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
     }

     return result;
  }
```

This is the code of my server:

```
  private void ListenForRequestsThreadStart(object contextObj)
  {
     ZmqContext context = (ZmqContext)contextObj;

     using (
        ZmqSocket frontend = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REP),
        backend = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.DEALER))
     {
        string bindAddress = string.Format("tcp://*:{0}", _listenForRequetsPort);
        frontend.Bind(bindAddress);
        backend.Bind("inproc://backend");

        frontend.ReceiveReady += HandleRequestReceived;

        // polling
     }
  }

  private void HandleRequestReceived(object sender, SocketEventArgs e)
  {
     string message;

     bool hasNext;
     do
     {
        message = socket.Receive(Encoding.ASCII);
        hasNext = socket.ReceiveMore;
     } while (hasNext);

     // after calling Receive 3 times i get my actual message
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sending via a socket you're at the mercy of the network. First, the network will have broken your message down in multiple packates each of which is received separately by your listener. Every now and then, the underlying socket on the listening machine will say to itself 'Got some incoming, but there's more to come. Wait a bit'. After a while it'll say, 'Oh well, give what I've got' and keep waiting'.

That's what's happening. In WCF, the WCF implementation gets its data via sockets which do exactly the same thing. But WCF waits till the whole message arrives before giving it to your waiting code. That's one of the advantages of using a Framework like WCF. It protects you from the metal.

Comment: Ok i understand that tcp splits messages into multiple segments. I thought zmq would abstract this for me and wait until the whole message has arrived because thats really low level protocol specific stuff. Do i really need to do this by myself?

Comment: I'd check the ZMQ docs, but the ZmqSocket having a ReceiveMore() method implies that its quite possible for the message to arrive bit by bit. There may be some setting that says 'Wait till you've got the whole message before raising the Receive event'

Answer (score 0):

Any message sent over TCP may be divided into several packets depending on its size. That's why you should *never* assume to get a message in one go, but read until you're sure you've received everything.

Comment: Ok i understand that tcp splits messages into multiple segments. I thought zmq would abstract this for me and wait until the whole message has arrived because thats really low level protocol specific stuff. Do i really need to do this by myself?